# Android -Extending a relative layout / Image Transitions

Tags: android

I want to do a transition of 1 image to another and I am trying to follow [this](http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/image_transition_view_for_android) example:

But I am am still learning Android and am having problems working out how to make it work

I have a simple android project with 2 Java files; test and TransitionView and one layout file called test.

test is my start up activity and contains:

```
    public class test extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
    }
}
```

TransitionView contains the code from the example (with the images replaced for some of my own)

```
  public class TransitionView extends RelativeLayout {

    /** One of the two in-memory art images */
    private ImageView _artView1;
    /** The other of the two in-memory art images */
    private ImageView _artView2;
    /** Length of art view transition animation, in milliseconds */
    private final int ANIMATION_DURATION_MSEC = 1000;
    /** The underlying ImageSwitcher that performs transitions */
    private ImageSwitcher _imageSwitcher;
    /** Index into _imageIds array */
    private int _currentImage = 0;
    /** All available art image resource ids */

    private final Integer[] _imageIds = { R.drawable.grass,
            R.drawable.headland, R.drawable.horse, R.drawable.icebergs,
            R.drawable.island, R.drawable.sheep, R.drawable.road,
            R.drawable.shrek, R.drawable.waterfall, R.drawable.train };
        /**
     * Create a new instance.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The parent context
     */
    public TransitionView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        _imageSwitcher = new ImageSwitcher(context);
        Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                android.R.anim.fade_in);
        fadeIn.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MSEC);
        Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fadeOut.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MSEC);
        _imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(fadeIn);
        _imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(fadeOut);

        _artView1 = new ImageView(context);
        _artView1.setImageResource(_imageIds[_currentImage]);

        _artView2 = new ImageView(context);
        _artView2.setImageResource(_imageIds[_currentImage + 1]);

        LayoutParams fullScreenLayout = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        _imageSwitcher.addView(_artView1, 0, fullScreenLayout);
        _imageSwitcher.addView(_artView2, 1, fullScreenLayout);
        _imageSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
        addView(_imageSwitcher, fullScreenLayout);
    }
    /**
     * Change the currently displayed image
     * 
     * @param pageRight
     *            if true, the next image will be shown, else the previous image
     *            will appear
     */
    public void changePage(boolean pageRight) {
        _currentImage = (pageRight) ? (_currentImage + 1) : (_currentImage - 1);
        if (_currentImage < 0) {
            _currentImage = _imageIds.length - 1;
        } else if (_currentImage >= _imageIds.length) {
            _currentImage = 0;
        }

        if (_imageSwitcher.getCurrentView() == _artView1) {
            _artView2.setImageResource(_imageIds[_currentImage]);
            _imageSwitcher.showNext();
        } else {
            _artView1.setImageResource(_imageIds[_currentImage]);
            _imageSwitcher.showPrevious();
        }
    }
}
```

My Manifest looks as follows (incase it's the problem):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".test"  android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
          <activity android:name=".TransitionView"></activity>
    </activity>

</application>
```

and my layout file which I think may be the problem is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TransitionView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TransitionView>
```

I get the following error when I try and run it:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.companynamehere.test.imagetransition/Com.companynamehere.test.ImageTransition.test}:android.view.InflateException: Binary Xml file line #2: Error Inflating class Transition View
```

I know this is to do with the layout and trying to add the transitionview in the xml, but I don't know what I should be doing.
I tried setting the transitionview activity as the start activity but that didn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was throwing an error was because it was expecting a constructor with the parameter  "AttributeSet" as well as context

instead of this

```
  public TransitionView(Context context) {
~~~~~
}
```

this

```
public TransitionView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {

}
```

Eclipse wasn't showing this in the logcat when I asked the question, but now after a nights sleep and PC restart it is..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full package name of your Layout class in the layout XML. If the package name of `TransitionView` is `com.mydomain.myapp` then you need to refer to this in your XML as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mydomain.myapp.TransitionView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></com.mydomain.myapp.TransitionView>
```

Comment: In that case, please edit your question and add a full stacktrace of any exceptions that are in your logcat.

Comment: I have found my answer, I assumed it was the same error as yesterday eclipse wasn't showing anything at all in the Logcat when it force closed when I tried it with the full path, but today it is and I can see what's happening. See my Answer below